# Can you inspect what items have been processed by Resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I can't seem to find any documentation on this, but I noticed that when I do `Resque.info`, it displays that `x` number of jobs have been processed. Does it save that information so I can find out more about *what exatly* was processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detailed job history is not included by default with Resque. You will need to use the [resque-history](https://github.com/ilyakatz/resque-history/) plugin.